# jQuery draggable element with margin-left won't move left when using a containment

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

When using a containment on a draggable element, such as:

```
$('#bar').draggable({
    containment: 'document',
});
```

and this item contains a margin-left, such as:

```
#bar {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

it is impossible to drag the element to the left past that margin. A jsfiddle illustrating this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/z866K/2/

Why is this happening? Why, if 'containment' is removed, the element can be moved to the left without issues? Is there any work-around for this? I'm working on a project which is based on dragging inside a containment, which was also built using margin-left for positioning the draggable elements --don't ask me why, but the project is pretty big and I think that finding a work-around for this might be easier than a general rewrite of the whole system approach--.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle, check it out. 

by adding a wrapper to the bar div, it can move beyond its confines

Comment: You need to add a link. The current link points to old fiddle.

Comment: Please 'fork' my jsfiddle, and provide the new link, so that you don't overwrite the original one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I don't think that will work, since the margin-left has to be on the element itself, as this is a big system already built like that :(